# Location request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY not working well on some Android devices

Tags: android, kotlin, location, fusedlocationproviderclient, horizontal-accuracy

My app uses `FusedLocationProviderClient` to track the user's location when the app is running or in the background and it's working fine. But there are a few devices where location is not that accurate and sometimes jumps back and forth. All required permissions are granted.
The funny part is when the user opens google maps or starts to share live location via WhatsApp, my app is getting more accurate locations, and that brings me think that something is wrong with my implementation.

Here is the code I'm using

```
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback


    fun startLocationTracking() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 10000
            fastestInterval = 5000
            maxWaitTime = 12000
            smallestDisplacement = 50f
            priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)

                val location = locationResult.lastLocation
                Log.e(TAG,location.toString())
                Log.e(TAG,location?.accuracy.toString())
                

                // broadcast
                ...
            }
        }
    
        try {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        } catch (unlikely: SecurityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Location update ERROR: $unlikely")
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts/suggestions on this?